# Python: changing directory of Python package for development

Tags: python, pip

Suppose I have a python package in following directory:

```
c:\Python27\site-package\monster
```

I want to change it to local branch:

```
c:\ddey\dev
```

I went to the directory `c:\ddey\dev` where I have \monster developer package

and tried: `pip install -e .`

But it isn't changing the path. How do I know?
in python I tried following:

```
>>>import monster
>>>print(monster.__file__) 
c:\Python27\site-package\monster\__init__.pyc
```

expected:

```
>>>import monster
>>>print(monster.__file__) 
c:\ddey\dev\monster\__init__.pyc
```

solution:
previously my pip install was getting completed but I never getting the following message at the end of it as shown below. There was an issue with a package during the operation which I didn't notice as pip install wasn't giving a clear error.Once I fixed the issue with the package, the installation worked fine and got expected result!

**`Successfully installed monster`**

Comment: Why not use [tag:virtualenv]?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip install --target=d:\path\not_default package_name`